# Creating a variable if key term appears in text

Tags: excel, spss

I am trying to create a variable "thromboembolism death", 0 if it is not the cause of death, 1 if it is.

Is there any way to sort through this data set through spss / excel in order to create a new variable if one of the key terms e.g (DVT, Pulmonary embolism, thromboembolism) appear in the line of text? Here is what my data looks like right now.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDrBs.png

Also the data set is very large. 250000+ cases. I am new to data analysis, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In SPSS, assuming you have a variable named `death_cause` with description verbatims:

```
COMPUTE thromboembolism_death = (INDEX(UPCASE(death_cause),'DVT') > 0)
  OR (INDEX(UPCASE(death_cause),'PULMONARY EMBOLISM') > 0)
  OR (INDEX(UPCASE(death_cause),'THROMBOEMBOLISM') > 0).
EXE .
```

In Excel, you could take a similar approach.  Assuming your text verbatims are in column A:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DVT",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PULMONARY EMBOLISM",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("THROMBOEMBOLISM",A1))),1,0)
```

Alternatively, if you're comfortable using `SUMPRODUCT()`, the formula gets a bit shorter.  Assuming you list your "strings to search for" in cells C2:C5:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2:C5,A1)))>0
```

Note that all of the above options are case-insensitive.